# C++ reading some bytes at a memory address, output as string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, pointers

A function returns a pointer and a length (via the arguments) from an unknown DLL.

```
Result = SpamnEggs( &pBytes, &nBytes )
```

The pointer points to a valid memory address at which are nBytes sequential bytes.
These bytes contain valid ascci values for text. There is no null termination!

I am tasked with "ovelaying" a string type of some sort in as few **simple** operations in generic C++ code (without complex libraries or using byte) before output:

```
cout << sresult
```

Added:
without copying the bytes as this is a large buffer that must be traversed.

Prototype:

```
int SpamnEggs( void* pBytes, void* nBytes );

becomes

int SpamnEggs( char** pBytes, int* nBytes );
```

Many thanks all. Great answers and all very valid.

Comment: With overlaying you mean you are not allowed to copy the char sequence? Or would that be a possible approach?

Comment: You are supposed to create a brand new class to handle these strings? Or can you just use `std::string my_string(static_cast<char*>(pointer), length)`?

Comment: could use std:string yes. Let me test that idea...

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: This constructor copies the whole string. That is not what he wants to do.

Comment: @Mike: `std::string` will copy the buffer.

Comment: If we are writing to `cout`, will an additional copy be noticeable? Premature optimizations, and all that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just construct a std::string from the pointer and a length.

```
std::string sResult(pBytes, nBytes);
std::cout << sResult;
```

(assuming `pBytes` is a `char*` pointer, otherwise you need a small cast).

Comment: I can change the prototype from Void*

Comment: Thats a simple and clean approach. But it copies the source data which I think/thought was not intended by the OP.

Comment: @Kit - like I commented on the question: "If we are writing to `cout`, will an additional copy be noticeable?". Doing I/O is a lot more complicated than constructing a string.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Agreed, that was just a remark to explain the difference between the solutions. Depending on the size of the data and the target stream it might make a difference or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the raw memory and add the string terminating character yourself:

```
char* newStr = new char[size + 1];
memcpy ( newStr, source, size );
newStr[size] = "\0";
cout << newStr;
```

Without copying memory, you can create a class that holds the pointer and length as members and overload the stream operator to print only `length` characters:

```
class MyString
{
   void* _pBuf;
   int _length;
public:
   MyString(void* pBuf, int length)
   {
      _pBuf = pBuf;
      _length = length;
   }

   friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &os,const MyString& obj);
};


ostream& operator <<(ostream &os,const MyString& obj)
{
   const char* pChar = (const char*)obj._pBuf;
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < obj._length ; i++ )
   {
      os << pChar[i];
   }
   return os;
}
```

Example usage:

```
   char* x = "blablabla";
   int length = 3;
   MyString str(x,length);
   cout << str;
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, no copymem.

Comment: not homework, the end of a long day for a simple soultion for a demo app that wont freak out client!

Comment: very nice solution, and technically great... just too many notes.

Answer (score 1):

What you would have to do is

a) Create some class that encapsulates the char pointer and the size.

b) Write a << operator for that class to output its content to a stream.

EDIT: In contrast to the response by Bo Persson this would not imply copying the source data.

Comment: its got to be simple and in line

Comment: I believe there is no way for everything inline. The class can be very lightweight and the shift operator is a one line (just loop and output each character). That done, the actual call will look like this: cout << MyString(charPointer, length); Look at the solution from Luchian, it seem correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (**untested**) code:

```
class my_pointer_string
{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const my_pointer_string &);

public:
    my_pointer_string(void *ptr, size_t len)
        : m_pointer(ptr), m_length(len)
        { }

private:
    void  *m_pointer;
    size_t m_length;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const my_pointer_string &str)
{
    char *string = reinterpret_cast<char *>(str.m_pointer);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.m_length; i++)
        os << *string++;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: great, but think simple, just a few lines so they dont get distracted from the important code